# Persist display after submit

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have the following code where a text input box accepts an url and if it is valid it should create a display area and provide a nice preview of the url.

The function works except, right after `submit`, display is available for few seconds and then it vanishes. I probably know the reason, after submit, the text area gets blank. How do I fix that ?

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Microlink from '@microlink/react';
import { String } from 'core-js';
import Card from '@material-ui/core/Card';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import { FormControl } from '@material-ui/core';

function validURL(str) {
  var pattern = new RegExp('^(https?:\\/\\/)?'+ // protocol
    '((([a-z\\d]([a-z\\d-]*[a-z\\d])*)\\.)+[a-z]{2,}|'+ // domain name
    '((\\d{1,3}\\.){3}\\d{1,3}))'+ // OR ip (v4) address
    '(\\:\\d+)?(\\/[-a-z\\d%_.~+]*)*'+ // port and path
    '(\\?[;&a-z\\d%_.~+=-]*)?'+ // query string
    '(\\#[-a-z\\d_]*)?$','i'); // fragment locator
  return !!pattern.test(str);
}

function App (){
  const [myurl, setMyurl] = useState("")
  const [display, setDisplay] = useState(false)

  const handleChange = (event) => {    
    var str = validURL(myurl)
    console.log(str)
    str ? setDisplay(true) : setDisplay(false)
  }

  return (    
    <form onSubmit={event => handleChange(event)} >
      <TextField
        id="outlined-name"
        label="Name"        
        margin="normal"
        variant="outlined"
        value={myurl}
        onChange={e => setMyurl(e.target.value)}
      />

      <Button
        type="submit"
        variant="contained"                          
      >
       Submit
      </Button>

      {display ? 
      <Card>
      <Microlink url={myurl}/>;        
    </Card> : null}


    </form>

  )
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const handleChange = (event) => {    
    event.preventDefault()
    var str = validURL(myurl)
    console.log(str)
    str ? setDisplay(true) : setDisplay(false)
  }
```

This did the trick but I would be interested in hearing views if there is something else that I am missing:

```
    event.preventDefault()
```

Comment: Nope. You are right. When form is submitted it was reloading page thereby resetting your `url`.